# Cartesian Product - compute the number of unique combinations

Tags: elementary-set-theory

given the number of sets 
and given the number of elements in each set
What mathematical equation efficiently computes the number of unique combinations
Example:
lets say there are 3 sets {1,2,3},{1},{1,2}
and we know that the 3 sets have 3,1,2 elements respectively
The Cartesian product would be {(1,1,1),(1,1,2),(2,1,1),(2,1,2),(3,1,1),(3,1,2)} and thus the count of these 'unique combinations' would be 6.

I'm looking for the math, that would allow me to find the count without calculating the Cartesian product first

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, it is just the product of the cardinalities of each set

Comment: @Abramo could you elaborate on that with an example please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, it is just the product of the cardinalities of each set.

As an example, let $A$ and $B$ be sets of cardinality $a$ and $b$ respectively. For each of the $a$ elements of $A$ we have a different combination for every element of $B$, so in total we have $a\cdot b$ possible combinations.

Starting from this you can easily prove my claim by induction.